# Providing a color function for ListPointPlot3D

Tags: color, plotting

Is there a way to write `ListPointPlot3D` expression, so when given a list of points, the the color of the points plotted is a function of the index/element number of the list?

Suppose `list` contains the points to be plotted and the color function is `Blend[{Yellow, Brown}, n]`, with `n` being the index a point in `list`, then `list[[1]]` should be yellow and `list[[-1]]` should be brown.

I feel like I'm almost there, but I cannot manage to combine the pieces, hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `VertexColors` is efficient if there are many points.

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];
```

Post-process `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]] /. 
 Point[pp_] :> 
  Point[pp, VertexColors -> (Blend[{Yellow, Brown}, #] & /@ Rescale@Range@Length[pp])]
```

Or directly with `Graphics3D`:

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], 
  Point[pts, VertexColors -> (Blend[{Yellow, Brown}, #] & /@ Rescale@Range@Length[pts])]},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4`}, Axes -> True
 ]
```

In both cases I get indistinguishable graphics:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Doing this with ListPointPlot3D is not very straightforward, but do look at the answer by m_goldberg.

However, `ListPointPlot3D` is trivial to re-implement in terms of graphics primitives.  Here's one way to colour based on index:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];

Graphics3D[
 {PointSize[Large],
  MapIndexed[{Blend[{Yellow, Brown}, First[#2]/Length[pts]], Point[#1]} &, pts]}
]
```

The second argument of `Blend` must be a number between 0 and 1, so we needed to divide the index by the total number of points.

Answer (score 3):

In V10, with the new association objects, it is easy to implement what you want with `ListPointPlot3D` What is needed is a hash map (which is my mental image of an association) that maps your list of points into index values for `Blend`. This can be built with `AssociationThread`. Consider

```
pts = RandomInteger[99, {100, 3}];
indxs = AssociationThread[pts, Range @ Length @ pts/Length @ pts];
ListPointPlot3D[pts,
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large]},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Yellow, Brown}, indxs[{##}]] &)]
```

[image: 3DPlot]

Comment: Fair enough, removed that remark.  And +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[pts,
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Blend[{Yellow, Brown}, 
    Position[pts, {x, y, z}][[1, 1]]/Length[pts]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];

ListPointPlot3D[List /@ pts, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
   PlotStyle -> Table[Blend[{Yellow, Brown},i/Length[pts]], {i, Length[pts]}]]
```

[image]